# Creating Patch for Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, patch

Does anyone know how to create a patch for WordPress plugin?
I need to release the latest version of an existing plugin without making conflicts. I am new to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally patch files are knows as diff files and they contains .diff extension. They are used to patch the difference between old and new file so that you can easily apply the patch.

Patch can be generated by several tools over several systems. Here is a [document](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/tutorials/trac/submitting-a-patch/) for that

I suggest you to use Mac/Linux Command Line ,

generate a diff file

```
svn diff filename.php > filename.diff
```

apply patch

```
patch -p0 < patch.diff
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this related with readme.txt? I need to update the wordpress plugin version  for that i have readme.txt file. So how to create patch for this?

Comment: svn diff readme.txt > filename.diff , this will provide you a patch file

Comment: Actually, I want to update my custom WordPress plugin. How can I release the new version of word press plugin? Also, I need to Inform Customers by including "New Wordpress version available. Click to Update Now" by adding appropriate messages.

Comment: Hello, What is the use of patch -p0 < patch.diff when I tried it is showing this patching file transport_business_locator.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]